# passing arg 2 of --- discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, warnings

I am having the following problem:

```
void send_Msg(const char* msg)
  {
  #if channel_free
      (void) din_send_msg(channel, msg); // (void) rcd_send_msg(int channel, char* msg);
  #else
      (void) cin_sendMsg(channel, msg);
  #endif
```

`(void) din_send_msg(channel, msg);`
gives me the warning "Passing arg 2 of 'din_send_msg' discards qualifiers from pointer target type".

I know that is because `din_send_msg` takes an int and a `char*` as parameters and it makes my `const char*` to a `char*`. Changing `(void) din_send_msg(int channel, char* msg);` to `(void) din_send_msg(int channel, const char* msg);` and assigning the `const char*` to a local pointer didn't do anything. But there's a good possibility, that I just did it wrong.

How can I deal with this warning?

(And yes, I absolutely have to get rid of it, even though it is just a warning)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you can modify `din_send_msg` to expect a pointer to const character, this would be best. And it should fix that warning. Same will apply to `cin_sendMsg` if it has same prototype.

Comment: If you are sure that those functions will never modify the memory content, you can also just use a cast.

Comment: The problem is that it is not my code :c And the person who asked me to find a solution also knows nothing. I mean, it is ours, but there are no people around anymore, who knows what this code is about. Also, another project with the same functions doesn't have a warning. Which is weird. And we couldn't find the way they dealt with it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is, if the function `din_send_msg` is yours, and it is certain that it does not modify characters pointed to by the pointer is to change the prototype of the function everywhere and throughout to use

```
returntype din_send_msg(int channel, const char *msg);
```

I do not know what the actual return type of the function is.

If you can't do that, then you can usually use a *cast* to silence the warning:

```
din_send_msg(channel, (char *)msg);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you :)
Apparently, as a new user, I cannot upvote :c

Comment: Well, of course, you _can_ silence the warning with a cast. But.... ugh :/ That's surely got to be the very last resort?